# How To Remove WordPress Version From The Admin Footer

Tags: admin, wp-admin, footer

Is there anyway to remove version number from the right side of WordPress admin footer?

I know this code will add some text before the version number, but it will not remove it:

```
function change_footer_version() {
    echo 'Anything';
}
add_filter( 'update_footer', 'change_footer_version', 9999 );
```

And the following code will do nothing:

```
function change_footer_version() {
    return ' ';
}
add_filter( 'update_footer', 'change_footer_version', 9999 );
```

So, is there anyway to remove the entire `<div>` from the template or anything with `functions.php` file?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add this to your `functions.php`:

```
function my_footer_shh() {
    remove_filter( 'update_footer', 'core_update_footer' ); 
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_footer_shh' );
```

or, if you'd like to hide it from everyone except admins:

```
function my_footer_shh() {
    if ( ! current_user_can('manage_options') ) { // 'update_core' may be more appropriate
        remove_filter( 'update_footer', 'core_update_footer' ); 
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_footer_shh' );
```

Comment: The function `is_admin()` merely checks if you're loading the admin screen. You should test the capabilities of the current user using something like `current_user_can( 'manage_options' )` instead. So, more precisely: `if ( !current_user_can('manage_options') ) { remove_filter( 'update_footer', 'core_update_footer' ); }`

Answer (score 6):

The other answer is not working for my site. I tried this script instead and it works fine for removing the WordPress version number from the right footer of admin pages:

```
add_filter( 'admin_footer_text', '__return_empty_string', 11 ); 
add_filter( 'update_footer', '__return_empty_string', 11 );
```

Comment: I tried instead this script and It works fine :                                       add_filter( 'admin_footer_text', '__return_empty_string', 11 );
add_filter( 'update_footer',     '__return_empty_string', 11 );

Comment: this code removes the left side of WordPress credits as well

Comment: doc for [__return_empty_string](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__return_empty_string/)

Answer (score 0):

Add this simple code into your function.php file:

```
function wpbeginner_remove_version() {
return '';
}
add_filter('the_generator', 'wpbeginner_remove_version');
```

Comment: the question was about admin area